# Hasse diagram with “≥” relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, lattice-orders

We have a set S= {1,2,3,4} with following relation: **aRb <-> a ≤ b ≤ a^2**

With focus on the relation we get following partially ordered set:
{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},
{2,3},{2,4},
{3,4}

which gives the following hasse diagram.

4
 |
 3
 |
 2
 |
 1

also we get a straight line from 1 to 4.

But i am a bit unsure if this is right, so am i thinking right?

Comment: Is $1\leq 2\leq 1^2$?  Given that information, is $1R2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of ordered pairs isn’t right, I’m afraid. First, you’ve omitted the pairs $\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle$, and $\langle 4,4\rangle$, all of which are in $R$: for any positive integer $n$ it’s true that $n\le n\le n^2$. Next, you have a lot of pairs that aren’t in $R$. For instance, it’s not true that $1\le 2\le 1^2$, so $\langle 1,2\rangle\notin R$. Similarly, $\langle 1,3\rangle\notin R$ and $\langle 1,4\rangle\notin R$. It is true, though, that $2\le 3\le 2^2$ and $2\le 4\le 2^2$, so you’re correct in thinking that $\langle 2,3\rangle$ and $\langle 2,4\rangle$ are in $R$. Similarly, $3\le 4\le 3^2$, so $\langle 3,4\rangle\in R$, as you said.

This is going to change your Hasse diagram a bit; I’ll let you see if you can correct on your own, but leave a question if you have problems.

Comment: alright , if i understood correctly. we have (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4) ?

Comment: and if we have  S= {1,2,3,4,.....,59,60},how do we find all the ordered pairs, it will be insanse to test for every number ? any shortcut ?

Comment: @humble24: Yes, your list in the first question is correct. If $S=\{1,\ldots,60\}$, and the relation is defined the same way, it’s not a partial order, because it’s not transitive: $\langle 2,4\rangle$ and $\langle 4,16\rangle$ are in the relation, but $\langle 2,16\rangle$ is not, because it’s not true that $2\le 16\le 2^2$. It wouldn’t be too hard to describe the ordered pairs, though: since $8^2=64$, they’ll include all pairs $\langle m,n\rangle$ such that $8\le m\le n\le 64$. After that you need only list the ones that have $7$ or smaller as first coordinate. That will be all pairs ...

Comment: ... $\langle 7,n\rangle$ with $7\le n\le 49$, all pairs $\langle 6,n\rangle$ with $6\le n\le 36$, and so on.